# Cannot determine the module for class TimeAgoPipe

Tags: angular, timeago

> Error: Cannot determine the module for class TimeAgoPipe in /Users/name/Documents/'full path here'/node_modules/time-ago-pipe/time-ago-pipe.d.ts! Add TimeAgoPipe to the NgModule to fix it.

I have correctly imported the Pipe in the module as below:

```
import {NgModule, Pipe} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { TimeAgoPipe as  TimeAgo} from "time-ago-pipe";

 @Pipe({
        name: 'timeAgo',
        pure: false
    })
    export class TimeAgoPipe extends TimeAgo {};

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        CommonModule, 
        FormsModule,
    ],
    exports:[ 
        TimeAgoPipe
    ],
    declarations: [
        TimeAgoPipe
    ],
    providers:[
    ]
})

export class TimeAgoPipeModule {}
```

I have already referred to other issues on stackoverflow but none of the solutions helped.

Comment: Do you have `TimeAgoPipeModule` added to the `imports` of `AppModule`?

Comment: Yes I have imported it in the AppModule and also added it to the imports array there

Comment: Try restarting the server (npm start again.)

Comment: tried that , it didn't help, is there an alternative library to timeago pipe?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-ago-pipe See if that works.

Comment: This is the one I am using currently, it keeps throwing an error

Comment: Seeing that the library is quite old, I am thinking it is a version mismatch. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-timeago Try this one.